# Dividing a set of points into two sets of roughly equal diameter

Tags: combinatorics, optimization, combinatorial-geometry, discrete-optimization

Let $S$ be a finite set whose cardinality is more than 1 and $d: S\times S\rightarrow\mathbb R$ be a positive symmetric function (that is, $d$ is a distance without the axiom of triangle inequality). For a subset $A, B$ of $S$ let $D(A) =\max_{(u,v)\in A^2} d(u,v)$ and $\mu(A,B) := \max\{D(A), D(B)\}$.  Consider the problem of minimizing $\mu(A,B)$ subject to the condition that $A\uplus B=S$.

Consider a tree $T$ whose vertex set is $S$.  Let $l(T) := \sum_{uv\in E(T)}d(u,v)$, where $E(T)$ is the edge set of $T$.  Noting that $T$ is 2-colorable, let $S_T$ be the set of elements of $T$ painted by one color and $S^\prime_T$ be the ones painted by the other.

I would like to show that if $T$ is such that $l(T)$ is maximum, $\mu(S_T,S^\prime_T)$ is minimum.

I would be grateful if you could give a clue as to how to prove the statment (not necessarily a complete proof).

Comment: In the definition of $D(A)$ as it now reads, the subset $A$ of $S$ does not appear on the right side. This makes $D(A)$ independent of $A$. Maybe the max should really be over $(u,v) \in A^2$.

Comment: @coffeemath Exactly.  I will edit the question.

Comment: "For a subset $A,B$ of $S$..." Do you mean $\{A,B\}$ form a *partition* of $S$? Otherwise I could take $A=B=\emptyset$ and have $\mu(A,B)=0$.

Comment: @RahulNarain Exactly.  I corrected the problem statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Let $d^*$ be the value of the optimal solution (that is, the minimum value of $\mu (A,B)$ over all partitions $(A,B)$ of $V$). Consider a maximum-cost spanning tree $T$. Let $\rho$ be the shortest path distance in $T$: $\rho(u,v)$ is the number of edges in the path between $u$ and $v$ in $T$.

We need to show that $d(u,v) \leq d^*$ for every $u$ and $v$ at even distance $\rho(u,v)$. Assume to the contrary that there exist $u$ and $v$ s.t. $d(u,v) > d^*$ and $\rho(u,v)$ is even. Then the path between $u$ and $v$ in $T$ and edge $(u,v)$ form a cycle $C$.

Show that

1. $C$ is an odd cycle;
2. for every edge $(u',v')$ in $C$, $d(u',v') > d^*$; use that $d(u,v) > d^*$ and $T$ is a maximum-cost spanning tree;
3. conclude that for every partition $(A,B)$, $\mu(A,B) > d^*$, and get a contradiction.

Comment: Thank you.  You take $d^*$ to be optimal at first.  Is this the value of $\mu(S_t,S^\prime_T)$ when $T$ is maximum spanning tree, or the optimal solution of the original optimization problem?

Comment: It is the optimal solution of the original optimization problem. I changed my answer to clarify that.

Comment: Could you please elaborate a little on 2.?

Comment: If $d(u',v') \leq d^*$ and $d(u,v) > d^*$ (as we assumed), then $T' = T + (u,v) - (u',v')$ is a spanning tree with $l(T') > l(T)$, which contradicts to our assumption that $T$ is a maximum cost spanning tree.